# .HTAccess file not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite url's and used the below code in .HTAccess, for some reason the link is not working if I add '/' in the last and is working properly if I don't add any '/'

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet.* [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight.* [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*HTTrack.*$ [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MemoWeb.*$ [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*FileHound.*$ 
    RewriteRule /* http://www.google.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: change `^([^/]+)/$` to `^([^/]+)/?$`, or the rewrite engine will match only url ending with a slash

Comment: I tried changing the Rewrite rule to `^([^/]+)/?$` but it didn't work

Comment: Post some example of link that works and some of not working links, then.  Just to have some data to work on. In the meantime, another blind attempt would be  `^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php`

Answer (score 0):

.HTAccess issue is resolved when I tried with the below code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/])$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet.* [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight.* [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*HTTrack.*$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MemoWeb.*$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*FileHound.*$ 
RewriteRule /* http://www.google.com/ [R,L]
```